# Is it possible to encode a file with certutil without creating new file?

Tags: windows, command-line, certutil

I'm encoding files with following command:

```
certutil -encode inputFileName encodedOutputFileName
```

However, this creates a new file on the system. Is it possible to print encoded data on command line and not write to a new file?

Comment: `certutil -encode -help` says that an output file name is mandatory. However, you could show its content using `type encodedOutputFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell instead

```powershell
[Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("path\to\file"))
```

If future PowerShell versions support process substitution like bash (or you have bash on your system) then you can use something like this

```powershell
certutil -encode inputFile >(/dev/tty)
```

Currently there may be some [workaround](https://serverfault.com/q/688645/343888) to achieve the same purpose. But why do that when both PowerShell and bash already have tools to encode/decode base64 contents?